# How to handle with null web service response?(axis2)

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm set up the web service by java、axis2,
there two response type : XML and JSON,

It's run when I call the webservice which having data,
but when the webservice response null data, the exception occurd.(following two picture)

and there is one part of my webservice function:

```
    public ViewStockHelpBuySheet[] getHelpBuySheet(String userid){
    Stock my=new Stock();

    ViewStockHelpBuySheet[] allStock=my.getHelpBuySheet(userid);
    allStock=new ViewStockHelpBuySheet[allStock.length];
    allStock=my.getHelpBuySheet(userid);
    return allStock;
}
```

so, how can I handle my null result ? did axis2 provides some way to handle that?
thanks

error picture:

http://ppt.cc/fcEt

http://ppt.cc/mWIL

Comment: I would guess you need to check for a null result before returning the response. The stack trace shows it cannot implicitly convert from a string(null) to a JSON object. Maybe create the JSON object first, then assign the values when you know it is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webservices are your programs..There is nothing special..You need to have your logic defined in it to handle your NPE exception or other type of exceptions..